# How to make overflow scroll to table data

Tags: html, css

Here is my Website link : http://rehmat.singlehtml.com
[image]

When i put "overflow:scoll" css to make scroll but when i did it makes my table td so small. I want full width of my td and scroll too. Any one ?

Here is the css of scroll

```
 tbody{
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
   }
```

Comment: Go to fiter -> by atrribute and you ll see a box

Comment: remove max-height:100px

Answer (score 1):

set display grid to tr

```
tr{
          display: grid;
    }
```